# Babel Optional Chaining

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I would like add `babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining` in my React Native project, but i've this error :

```
error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'loose' of undefined
    at _default (/home/user/project/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining/lib/index.js:12:32)
```

My **package.json** :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
},
```

Anyone have already test this babel plugin in React Native project ?

Thank you !

Comment: Has any of available answers answered your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned optional chaining is working only with babel v7, so you have to update from ver6 to ver7

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error as you when trying to use optional chaining inside a create-react-app. From what I understand, you need to be using babel core 7, and the default for CRA is 6. Which version are you using currently?

Comment: React Native use babel 6, i can't use Optionnal Chaninig with react-native for now. Maybe next update ? ^^

Comment: When they update babel is when I update react-scripts :)